# PHP log complete request

Tags: php, logging, request

Is it possible to log the request with PHP?
I also want to log the images, js, CSS file requests.

```
<img src="foo.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="foo.css">
```

I currently use this code but it only gives me the current request uri and not the other files etc.
I also rewritten all request to my index.php which I have this line of code in.

```
file_put_contents('foo.txt', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is one option to draw all http requests to a file. This applies to all requests that travel with the HTTP protocol

```
$myFile = "requestslog.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
    fwrite($fh, "\n\n--------------------------------------
        -------------------------\n");
    foreach($_SERVER as $h=>$v)
        if(ereg('HTTP_(.+)',$h,$hp))
            fwrite($fh, "$h = $v\n");
    fwrite($fh, "\r\n");
    fwrite($fh, file_get_contents('php://input'));
    fclose($fh);
    echo "<html><head /><body><iframe src=\"$myFile\" 
        style=\"height:100%; width:100%;\"></iframe></body></html>"
```

Comment: Thank you, kinda useful and fast thing)
I would only add that in PHP7+ line 
`if(ereg('HTTP_(.+)',$h,$hp))`
need to be replaced with `if(preg_match('/HTTP\_(.+)/',$h,$hp))`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. You can make all the requests pass through a php script, so that you can log the action. For example, a simple image request like `http://url.com/img.jpg` would became `http://url.com/index.php?action=download&file=img.jpg`, and the script would handle the logging, the file download and correct headers.

Also take into account that your http server might be logging the request already, take a look into the [access_log](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html) of apache if you are using it.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the approach listed on [this gist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/magnetikonline/650e30e485c0f91f2f40/raw/cbc114d0af29eaad80f75b69732d757971c71fd0/dumprequest.php).

```php
<?php
// https://gist.github.com/magnetikonline/650e30e485c0f91f2f40

class DumpHTTPRequestToFile {
    public function execute($targetFile) {
        $data = sprintf(
            "%s %s %s\n\nHTTP headers:\n",
            $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'],
            $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],
            $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']
        );

        foreach ($this->getHeaderList() as $name => $value) {
            $data .= $name . ': ' . $value . "\n";
        }

        $data .= "\nRequest body:\n";

        file_put_contents(
            $targetFile,
            $data . file_get_contents('php://input') . "\n"
        );

        echo("Done!\n\n");
    }

    private function getHeaderList() {
        $headerList = [];
        foreach ($_SERVER as $name => $value) {
            if (preg_match('/^HTTP_/',$name)) {
                // convert HTTP_HEADER_NAME to Header-Name
                $name = strtr(substr($name,5),'_',' ');
                $name = ucwords(strtolower($name));
                $name = strtr($name,' ','-');

                // add to list
                $headerList[$name] = $value;
            }
        }

        return $headerList;
    }
}


(new DumpHTTPRequestToFile)->execute('./dumprequest.txt');
```

You can quickly copy the above file by doing `curl -O https://gist.githubusercontent.com/magnetikonline/650e30e485c0f91f2f40/raw/cbc114d0af29eaad80f75b69732d757971c71fd0/dumprequest.php > dumprequest.php`.

The output will be something like

> GET /dumprequest.php HTTP/1.1
>
> HTTP headers: Authorization: User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.0 Accept:
> */* Cache-Control: no-cache Host: somehost.com Accept-Encoding: gzip,
> deflate, br Connection: keep-alive
>
> Request body: hi=ricardo

Answer (score -1):

```
// Reports all errors
error_reporting(E_ALL);
// Do not display errors for the end-users (security issue)
ini_set('display_errors','Off');
// Set a logging file
ini_set('error_log','request_log_file.log');
```

**Note- request_log_file.log - you can set your full file path here if needed.**

Hope this will help you!

Comment: The question is about logging a Request not an error during the request.